# Amazon AWS VPC peering network connectivity issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering

VPC Peering two system, but can't ping, creating VPC peering status is Showing **Active**.
Vpc Requester CIDRs and Accepter CIDRs mention and Added the Security group **All ICMP - IPv4**.
Updated the **Route Table**.

#### vpc1-routeTable

```
0.0.0.0/0   igw-09c18defa110efc89   
10.0.0.0/16 local   
192.168.0.0/16  pcx-0e64bf9b3a3706b40
```

---

#### vpc2-routeTable

```
0.0.0.0/0   igw-05d7c550b3f93b50a   
10.0.0.0/16 pcx-0e64bf9b3a3706b40   
192.168.0.0/16  local
```

All Step are followed, but it still connectivity issues.
Any idea if I'm missing anything here?

Comment: Is ICMP open to the relevant IPs?

Comment: If you're confident that you've set up the Security Groups correctly, the host firewalls allow ICMP, and the NACLs are default, then try [Reachability Analyzer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html).